# Draw a line between 2 GPS points using Metaio and Canvas

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I'm writing here because i'm modifying the GPS based example given by Metaio to try to show a line between 2 GPS points in an AR application. The example works well and i'm able to show an object ( image for example ) in a GPS loc., but when i try to implement Canvas appears many errors, so, my question is, what do i exactly need to draw a line using Metaio and Canvas? If It's impossible...what should i use?. I also have a problem doing the relationship between the screen coordinates and the real coordinates in the space that belongs to the gps points. I found this but i think i need the opposite:

virtual Vector3d metaio::IUnifeyeMobile::get3DPositionFromScreenCoordinates (   int     cosID,
const Vector2d &    point 
)        [pure virtual, inherited]
Converts screen coordinates to the corresponding 3D point on the plane of the tracked target.

Parameters:
cosID   The (one-based) index of the coordinate system in which the 3D point is defined.
point   The 2D screen coordinate to use.
Returns:
A 3D vector containing the coordinates of the resulting 3D point.

Sorry for my bad english and i'll be waiting for answers.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe Metaio hasn't been thought to draw using Canvas and its function is to deal with objects in AR apps because i'm not having any answer in its forum neither. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You might try asking your question at the Metaio Helpdesk:

http://helpdesk.metaio.com/

The site is watched by Metaio techs and has many Metaio/Junaio developers who participate. You might get an answer there quicker. If you do figure out the problem, be sure to post the solution back here!